# Oracle APEX 5.0 - SQL query based on (multiple) checkbox values

Tags: oracle, checkbox, oracle-apex

I have a list of values and it works as a list.

```
select KEY, VALUE
from keytable
WHERE key = :LOV_KEYLIST
```

This works perfectly fine.

However, if **I do the LOV as checkboxes, it doesn't work at all.**
Those checkboxes are a new item and I want them to change my select query from my interactive report.

How can I select multiple checkboxes and only get shown the rows where the values from the checkboxes apply?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because it multivalues (val1:val2:val3:valN..),
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/appdev.32/e13363/check_box.htm#CHDBGDJH

try this:

```
select KEY, VALUE
from keytable
-- check all posible values in checkbox item
WHERE (instr(':'||:LOV_KEYLIST||':',':'||key||':') >0 
         -- if value is null show All rows
         or :LOV_KEYLIST is null)
```

Comment: This is great and works perfectly. Could you explain the syntax of INSTR a little bit? I'm having trouble figuring it out.

Comment: The INSTR functions search string for substring. The function returns an integer indicating the position of the character in string that is the first character of this occurrence. In this case if INSTR > 0 that mean, what string contain substring (your ID_LIST - string, ID - substring) read more in official doc https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions068.htm

Comment: Ok, but since it return an integer that may be >0, how exactly does the select know, which rows to select? For me it looks like: "... WHERE 2 >0" as an example.

Comment: instr(..) > 0 means that key exists in keylist. (1:2:3:4 - your checkbox values, 3 - your fkey in table). if INSTR find substring ':3:' in string ':1:2:3:4:' then return position 5. 5 > 0 and thats why rows output

Comment: you can read this doc http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/appdev.32/e13363/check_box.htm#CHDBGDJH

Comment: Hey, I'm having trouble figuring this one out. What I want to do is: `SELECT * FROM view WHERE :LOV_KEYLIST IS NULL` but with Checkboxes as well. I don't know how to exactly form the `INSTR` function. Can you help me out?

Comment: hi man. i think that i don't exactly understand what you want, can you describe more information ?

Comment: Sure. I want to do the same as in the question, but now, the `WHERE` is turned around. So instead of `SELECT key, value from keytable WHERE key = :LOV_KEYLIST` I want to do `SELECT * FROM keytable WHERE :LOV_KEYLIST IS NULL`. The `:LOV_KEYLIST` is again made through Checkboxes and also contains the row names. So for example `english` is in `:LOV_KEYLIST`, so I want the query to be `SELECT * FROM keytable WHERE english IS NULL`.

Comment: i think understand you , you want to get rows where not containt that you select in checkboxed... try like this `WHERE not (instr(':'||:LOV_KEYLIST||':',':'||key||':') >0 `

Comment: Sorry, that is not what I want. Let's say I have the query `SELECT * FROM keytable WHERE english IS NULL`. But now I want to replace `english` with Checkboxes (LOV) called `LOV_KEYLIST` that has `english`, `russian` and `german` as values. So I want to have `SELECT * FROM keytable WHERE english IS NULL AND german IS NULL` for example. Since I want it with Checkboxes, I'm using `LOV_KEYLIST` and want to replace `WHERE english IS NULL` with `WHERE :LOV_KEYLIST IS NULL`

Comment: Yes, those are also the column names

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118295/discussion-between---and-oldmcdonald).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code

```
 column in (
          
          select regexp_substr(:P100_VERSION,'[^:]+', 1, level) ID from dual
connect by regexp_substr(:P100_VERSION, '[^:]+', 1, level) is not null
          
          
        )
```